# Order by most of items with Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a 'items' table with the following structure:

```
id, person_id, active
```

and 'people' table with id and name columns.

I want to order by most active items and join the people.name column to sql.

I tried to do something like that, but it's not working:

```
SELECT people.id, COUNT(*) as items_count
FROM items, people
WHERE items.active = true AND people.id = items.person_id
GROUP BY items.person_id
ORDER BY items_count DESC
```

Comment: implicit joins are a SQL antipattern, please learn to use explicit joins instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Joins this will match the condition. Order by items_count will give you most active user

```
Select people.id, COUNT(items.active) as items_count
FROM items
LEFT JOIN people on  people.id = items.person_id
WHERE items.active = true
GROUP BY people.id
ORDER BY items_count DESC
```

Comment: The Left Join takes all of the records in your first table. If the ON statement is not true, it simply NULLS the values in the second table's column for that recordset. Otherwise in case of INNER JOIN it wont compare all rows of first table when ON statement is false. This will help you when item_count is 0

Comment: Oh, so if I don't want to count 0 i'll do INNER JOIN?

Comment: yes inner join wont show any result when people table doesnot contain any related entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select * from (SELECT people.id, COUNT(*) as items_count
    FROM items
    left outer join people on  people.id = items.person_id
    where items.active = true
    GROUP BY items.person_id) as A
    ORDER BY A.items_count DESC
```